# primefaces make clientValidation="true", but oncomplete doesn't work

Tags: csv, primefaces, client-side-validation

```
<p:commandButton update="${update}" disabled="#{!controller.canSave}" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk" actionListener="#{controller.save}" oncomplete="${oncomplete}" validateClient="true"/>
```

above is part of my code, oncomplete works when `validateClient="false"`, but when it changes to `validateClient="true"`, oncomplete is not executed any more.

Please share your suggestion, thanks very much.

Comment: When you have `validateClient="true"` does every component pass validation?

Comment: @Geinmachi , yes, validation like '@NotNull', '@Size' which defined in JPA bean will be validated in client side.